# Randomly chosen points in higher dimensional spaces

Tags: probability, geometry, statistics

Consider a $d$-dimensional Euclidean space. Generate $n$ points at random where each coordinate is a standard normal random variable. (The coordinates are independent random variables.) The book 'Foundations of Data Science' by Blum, Hopcroft and Kannan claims that "For sufficiently large $d$, with high probability the distances between all pairs of points will be essentially the same".

I am unable to prove this statement. This is the way I proceeded. Let $x$ and $y$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_d)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_d)$. Let $\rho^2$ be the square of the Euclidean distance between them. Then its expectation is $\mu = 2d$ and standard deviation is $\sigma = \sqrt{4d(d-1)}$. Both these quantities diverge as $d \rightarrow \infty$. In what sense can we say that "distances between all pairs is essentially the same"?

The ratio $\sigma/\mu$ tends to $1$ in the limit $d \rightarrow \infty$. But surely, that is not the measure of distance.

The book 'Foundations of Data Science' is available at https://www.cs.cornell.edu/jeh/book2016June9.pdf.

Comment: You've found the expectation and standard deviation of the *square* of the Euclidean distance.

Comment: @Rahul, the square is easier to deal with analytically than the quantity itself. Further, the square too will be 'essentially the same' if the distance is 'essentially the same'.

Comment: Sure but your statement "Let $\rho^2$ be the Euclidean distance" is false. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution

Comment: @Rahul, fine I edited the post to mention that I am dealing with the square of the distance.

Comment: @Rahul thanks for pointing me the Wikipedia link. However, the variable $Y$ is the not the Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_i^2 = (x_i - y_i)^2$. We have that $Z_i^2 / 2$ follows $\chi^2(1)$ distribution and thus
$$
\mathsf{E}(Z_i^2) = 2\quad\text{and}\quad \mathsf{Var}(Z_i^2) = 8
$$
Therefore,
$$
\mathsf{E}(\rho^2) = 2d\quad\text{and}\quad\mathsf{Var}(\rho^2) = 8d
$$
By Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\Pr(|\rho^2 - 2d| \geq d^{3/4}) \leq \frac{8}{\sqrt{d}}
$$
That is, with probability at least $1 - \frac{8}{\sqrt{d}}$, $\rho^2$ is in the range $[2d - d^{3/4}, 2d + d^{3/4}]$. If $d = 81n^8$, we can state that "with probability at least $1 - \frac{8}{9n^4}$, $\rho^2$ is in the range $[162n^8 - 27n^6, 162n^8 + 27n^6]$.

Note that $\rho^2$ is the squared Euclidean distance between two points. We further have by union bound that
$$
\Pr(\text{all distances between points are in }[162n^8 - 27n^6, 162n^8 + 27n^6]) \geq 1 - \frac{8n^2}{9n^4} \ge1 - \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
from which we conclude that the distances between points are nearly the same.

Comment: And yet there is a bit of a dissatisfaction because the $\epsilon$ in Chebeshyev's inequality depends on $d$.